# Xtext - Get cross-referenced child

Tags: children, xtext, cross-reference

I have a grammar that looks like:

```
A:
myField=[B]

B:
C | D | E
```

I have a function that gets A (let's say a) as a parameter and I want to access C, for example.
I did a.myField that returns a B object (let's say b). Than I used 
EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(b,C) - but it returns an empty list.

Maybe the reason is that B is not really parsed again, but cross-referenced. If so, is there any function that allows me to access C/D/E in the above example?

Thank you.

**Update**

Apparently b is null, so of course getAllContentsOfType() returns an empty list. How do I access B (which is cross-referenced from A)?

Comment: @RadLexus - Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to check that a.myField isn't null.